# Can't Create System Link in Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am trying to create a system link on a docker container running ubuntu. I'm using docker-compose to launch the container.

In `services.yml` I have...

```
...
services:
  test:
    depends_on:
      - couchbase
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: test-dev.dockerfile
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /var/www/modules/test
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - NODE_APP_INSTANCE=docker
      - DEBUG=test-api:*
    command: bash -c 'sh ../../docker/test-dev.init.sh && yarn && yarn dev'
```

In `test-dev.dockerfile` I have:

```
FROM couchbase:community-6.5.1

# Install node and yarn
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y curl apt-transport-https gnupg && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
    apt -y install curl dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && \
    apt update && \
    apt install -y yarn nodejs

# Add node user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash  node && usermod -aG sudo node
```

In test-dev.init.sh I have...

```
ln -s /opt/couchbase/bin/cbbackupmgr /var/www/modules/dir/bin/cbbackupmgr
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
 ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/www/modules/backupmgr/bin/cbbackupmgr'$'\r': 
Permission denied
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess the dockerfile is for `couchbase`, you should afford the `test-dev.dockerfile`

Comment: `$'\r':` Your file has dos line endings. You might want to run it via `dos2unix`

Comment: Is the "node" user have the good rights to write in "`/var/www/modules/dir/bin`" directory ?
Also, the error line finish by '\r'. Can you verify that your script is with "`\n`" (aka LF) end of line (UNIX EOL format) and not with "`\r\n`" (CR LF) end of line (Windows EOL format) ?